# Laravel - can't get auth::atempt to work properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

```
   $inputs["mail"] = Input::get('mail');
    $password = Hash::make(Input::get("password","")); 
    $user = new User(); 
    $user->password=$password;
    $inputs["password"] = $password;
     if( Auth::attempt($inputs) )
    {
        return 'loginOK';
    }
    else
    {
        return 'false';
    }
```

i think that $password is different from password of database.
Do I need to try to other way?

```
<?php
    use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
    use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

    class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface,          

    RemindableInterface {
    protected $table ='users';
    public function getAuthIdentifier(){
        return $this->getKey();
    }
    public function getRememberToken(){
        return $this->remember_token;
    }
    public function getAuthPassword(){
        return $this->password;
    }
    public function setRememberToken($value){
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }
    public function getRememberTokenName(){
        return 'remember_token';
    }
    public function getReminderEmail()  {
        return $this->email;
    }
   }
```

it is User model.

can't get auth::atempt to work properly
what problem is it?

```
$input = [
    'mail' => Input::get('mail'),
    'password' => Input::get('password'),
　];

　if (Auth::attempt($input)) {
    echo 'Success';
　} else {
    echo 'Failed';
　}
```

I edited　by　folower.
I have som trouble.
still i cant get

Comment: Don't hash the password you pass to `attempt()`! Also why would you create a new User model?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are passing the Hashed password to the attempt method, that method actually expect the unhashed password and does the hashing itself, so doing:

```
$inputs["password"] = Input::get('password');
```

should do the trick.

I'm not sure if your playing around but your code is not properly written and you should consider using the Input object directly.

Comment: `Input::only('mail', 'password')` FTW ;)

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You don't need to hash the password
2. You don't need to make a user model.

It is enough to do something as follows:

```
$input = [
    'mail' => Input::get('mail'),
    'password' => Input::get('password'),
];

if (Auth::attempt($input)) {
    echo 'Success';
} else {
    echo 'Failed';
}
```

Comment: but I could not login.what is other problem?

Comment: string(46) "select * from "users" where "mail" = ? limit 1" why?

Comment: It depends on your User model. Maybe it is `email` instead of `mail`?

Comment: When you created the user and stored it in the database, did you use `Hash::make()` to generate its password?

Comment: No, I didnt use Hash::make().

Comment: I created its password directly with pgadmin.